# Eclipse how do I change the button background color back to default

Tags: android, button

What is the default background color of the button. 
Please tell me the background color in a form of a html color code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android basically has different themes. Themes decide what style to apply to a widget. The themes are defined in the themes.xml file under the path

> android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\values\themes.xml

Now we need to find the style for Button defined in themes.xml. When you for it you will find something like :

```
<!-- Button styles -->

<item name="buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
```

This means that the theme applies the style Widget.Button to buttons. Now look for the style

> Widget.Button

This style will be defined in

```
android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\values\styles.xml
```

You will find something like below in themes.xml for Widget.Button

```
<style name="Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

Now what is of importance in the above code is the line

```
<item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default</item>
```

This means that there is a drawable called btn_default set as button background.

Now we need to find a file named btn_default.* in one of the drawable folders under android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res.

After a little bit searching you will find the file android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml

It will contain something like below :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
```

So this is a selector drawable. This selector chooses different backgrounds, based on the buttons state. For example a pressed button will have a different background than a non-pressed button.

So we need to look at the default (non-pressed) state of the Button.

```
<item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
```

So the following drawable is being applied here :

```
btn_default_normal
```

We now need to find a file named btn_default_normal.* in one of the drawable folders under android-sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res.

This can be again either an image or a xml file like btn_default_normal.xml.

Now You will find multiple files called 'btn_default_normal.9.png' in different drawable folders for different resolutions.

So now you know that there is no color with a specific hex code involved in this. Its a 9 patch image (btn_default_normal.9.png).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could just set the background color to @null.

Answer (score 0):

Simple - go to the layout \ see the code and delete the android:#color code ;-)